# Is there a way to get the method who threw exception's Namespace and class

Tags: c#, exception

I am trying to figure out the method who threw expection's Namespace and class and method name as string.
Basically some method is going to throw a exception and I need the those 3 information about the method.
It is kinda of a dumb question but I will really appreciate a help.

Comment: is the `.StackTrace` useful at all?

Comment: This is the sort of question that usually comes about when you find that your error logging/display is just using `ex.Message` and not `ex.ToString()` which contains far more useful information (including the stack trace that Marc mentions)

Comment: Have a look at `TargetSite`

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I fıgured it out thank you guys.

Comment: The StackTrace has these info. Keep in mind that the throw, rethrow  of your exception can royaly screw up your stackTrace.
Referring this article http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpThrowingExceptions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Coments on the question solved it. You can take a look at those.